# SQL sentence for two non relational tables for seacher

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a searcher for my webpage and i'm facing a little issue, i want to get the info from two non relationals tables but the data is not returning the way i want

**table 1**

```
ID |FNAME  |LNAME | STATE  | CITY 
------------------------------
1  |xxxxx1 |xxxxx1| xxxx1  | xx1     
2  |xxxxx2 |xxxxx2| toronto| xx2
3  |xxxxx3 |xxxxx3| xxxx3  | yy3
4  |zzzzz3 |zzzzz3| toronto| yy3
```

**table 2**

```
ID |NAME   | STATE  | CITY 
---------------------
1  |yyyyy1 | yyyy1  | yy1     
2  |yyyyy2 | yyyy2  | yy2
3  |yyyyy3 | toronto| yy3
```

currently i have

```
SELECT
    e.id_client, e.fname_client, e.city_client, e.state_client , m.id_client, m.fname_client, m.lname_client, m.state_client, m.city_client 
FROM 
    empresas e 
CROSS JOIN 
    medicos m 
WHERE 
    e.fname_client LIKE :busqueda 
OR 
    e.city_client LIKE :busqueda 
OR  
    m.fname_client LIKE :busqueda 
OR 
    m.lname_client LIKE :busqueda 
OR 
    m.state_client LIKE :busqueda 
OR 
    m.city_client LIKE :busqueda
```

this displays the result like this

```
ID| FNAME |LNAME | STATE  | CITY |ID|FNAME  |LNAME | STATE  | CITY 
3 |yyyyy3 |      | yyyy3  | yy3  |3 |xxxxx3 |xxxxx3| xxxx3  | yy3
```

but i want it like this

```
ID|FNAME  |LNAME | STATE  | CITY 
3 |xxxxx3 |xxxxx3| xxxx3  | yy3
3 |yyyyy3 |      | yyyy3  | yy3
```

EDIT:

with the UNION asnwer i get the data with the format i want, but is showing only the results from one table when i search for commons values, for example:

if i type "Toronto", this must shows

```
    ID|FNAME  |LNAME | STATE    | CITY 
    2 |xxxxx3 |xxxxx3| toronto  | yy3 <- doctor
    3 |yyyyy3 |      | toronto  | yy3 <- organization
    4 |zzzzz3 |zzzzz3| toronto  | yy3
```

but is only showing this

```
    ID|FNAME  |LNAME | STATE  | CITY 
    2 |xxxxx3 |xxxxx3| toronto  | yy3 <- doctor
    4 |zzzzz3 |zzzzz3| toronto  | yy3 <- doctor
```

Comment: you could do a UNION operation instead of a cross join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to *concatenate* the two tables. Then...

```
select 
    id, fname, lname, state, city
from 
    table1
where
    <your where condition here>
union all
select 
    id, fname, lname, state, city
from 
    table2
where
    <your other where condition here>
```

**EDIT**

If you have:

```
SQL> select * from table1 order by id;
 id |   fname    |   lname    |   state    |    city    
----+------------+------------+------------+------------
  1 | xxxxx1     | xxxxx1     | xxxx1      | xx1       
  2 | xxxxx2     | xxxxx2     | toronto    | xx2       
  3 | xxxxx3     | xxxxx3     | xxxx3      | xx3       
  4 | zzzzz3     | zzzzz3     | toronto    | yy3  
SQL> select * from table2 order by id;
 id |    name    |   state    |    city    
----+------------+------------+------------
  1 | yyyyy1     | yyyy1      | yy1       
  2 | yyyyy2     | yyyy2      | yy2       
  3 | yyyyy3     | toronto    | yy3
```

then:

```
select 
    id, fname, lname, state, city
from 
    table1
where
    state='toronto'
union all
select 
    id, name as fname, NULL as lname, state, city
from 
    table2
where
    state='toronto'
order by id;

 id |   fname    |   lname    |   state    |    city    
----+------------+------------+------------+------------
  2 | xxxxx2     | xxxxx2     | toronto    | xx2       
  3 | yyyyy3     | (null)     | toronto    | yy3       
  4 | zzzzz3     | zzzzz3     | toronto    | yy3
```

Comment: this almost worked perfectly, but , when i look for common results, it just shows the results from medicos, probably need to apply a outer join?

Comment: I guess the select on empresas returns no rows with your where condition... try to run it on its own. BTW what exactly you mean with "common results"? Please edit your question to add sample data for your two tables and the expected result.

Comment: i mean, for example if i type toronto, this must show all result with that word, but it only shows the doctors not the companys, but the query works, i ran it and reurns the values nicely. Gonna edit the question

Comment: @AlexanderPulido: where the id 4 come from in your desired result if your input tables (table1 and table2) do not have it?

Comment: i got mor or less the problem, when the ids are the same, for example 1 for medicos and empresas, it shows the first result, and that is the doctors because is the first table from the sentence